# pandas - More efficient way to calculate two Series with circular dependencies

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `DataFrame` that represents stock returns. To split adjust the closing price, I have the following method:

```
def returns(ticker, start=None, end=None):
    p = historical_prices(ticker, start, end, data='d', convert=True)
    d = historical_prices(ticker, start, end, data='v', convert=True)

    p['Dividends'] = d['Dividends']
    p['Dividends'].fillna(value=0, inplace=True)
    p['DivFactor'] = 1.
    p['SAClose'] = p['Close']

    records, fields = p.shape
    for t in range(1, records):
        p['SAClose'][t] = p['Adj Close'][t] / p['DivFactor'][t-1] + \
                          p['Dividends'][t-1]
        p['DivFactor'][t] = p['DivFactor'][t-1] * \
                            (1 - p['Dividends'][t-1] / p['SAClose'][t])

    p['Lagged SAClose'] = p['SAClose'].shift(periods=-1)
    p['Cash Return'] = p['Dividends'] / p['Lagged SAClose']
    p['Price Return'] = p['SAClose'] / p['Lagged SAClose'] - 1
    return p.sort_index()
```

Note how `SAClose` (i.e. Split Adjusted Close) depends upon lagged `DivFactor` values. In turn, `DivFactor` depends on both lagged `DivFactor` values as well as the current `SAClose` value.

The method above works, but it is incredibly slow in the loop section. Is there a more efficient way for me to do this in pandas? Given the "circular" dependency (not really circular given the lags), I'm not sure how I could do either regular series math or use normal shift operations (e.g as I do with `Cash Return`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try creating a cumulative adjustment factor series in one shot then you don't need to loop:

```
(p['Dividends'].fillna(1.) + 1.).cumprod()
```

Comment: You pushed me in the right direction ... DivFactor doesn't need to be circular with SAClose. That said, it seems to have a form (see edit) that isn't easily passed into `cumprod`. Any thoughts?